# Jquery issues with missing closing script tag '>'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
**<script**
<script language="jscript">
<!--
    function OnLoad()
    {

        try
        {
           Some code here
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            Some code here
        }
    }

    function OnUnload()
    {
        try
        {
            Some code here
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            Some code here
        }
    }
-->
</script>
</head>
<body style="background: url(..\ABC.gif) #ffffff fixed no-repeat;" onload="OnLoad()" onunload="OnUnload()">
</body>
</html>
```

Though it is not necessary I have two script tags and the first one is not closed properly.
Interestingly my application is not giving any errors related to this. But I am facing some jquery issues like "XYZ" is null or not an object. Are these issues coming because of this wrong syntax by any chance? Will it lead to any other issues? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's parsing it as `<script <script language="jscript">` for the opening tag. It's just seeing the second `<script` as an attribute of the `<script>` tag.

Comment: See http://javascript.about.com/library/blhtmcmt.htm. Although unless you have to support truly ancient browsers I wouldn't bother including HTML Comment marks. Every modern browser properly supports script tags these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag is being seen as this:

```
<script <script language="jscript">
```

The second `<script` is being interpreted as attribute of the `script` tag. It's an unrecognized attribute so it's ignored. It's not much different from:

```
<script blah language="jscript">
```

Comment: Thank you Plutoand Barmar. Will it cause any other damages to the application?